# Escaping in bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, gnome-terminal

Given a text message, I need to programmatically generate a bash command to open terminal emulator and show this text in it.
For example, for `HelloWorld` input string I need to return the following output string:
`gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c echo\ HelloWorld;exec\ $SHELL"`

The problem is that my input messages may consist of arbitrary symbols.
By trial and error, I have ascertained that different symbols are required to be escaped different number of times:

```
"A" must be converted to "A"        (0 times to be escaped)
" " must be converted to "\ "       (1 times to be escaped)
"(" must be converted to "\\\("     (2 times to be escaped)
"\" must be converted to "\\\\\\\\" (3 times to be escaped)
```

For example, `\(o o)/` must be inserted in the command as `\\\\\\\\\\\(o\ o\\\)\\\/`:
`gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c echo\ \\\\\\\\\\\(o\ o\\\)\\\/;exec\ $SHELL"`

Actually, I don't know bash at all, so I don't have full understanding of the logic behind that.
Could you please tell me the general rule: how to convert any symbol from ASCII subset (10,32-126)?

**Edit:**
To bring more clarity on what I'm doing.

I'm trying to write a function (in some programming language) that receives a string InputText and returns another string, which is a correct bash command.
Currently, I'm trying to implement this function as simple concatenation of:
1) constant prefix `gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c echo`
2) inner part which depends on InputText
3) constant suffix `;exec\ $SHELL"`
The problem is with the inner part.  I'm trying to calculate it as concatenation of each InputText's symbol converted.  But I don't know how to convert arbitrary symbol.

**Edit 2:**
Thanks to choroba for the idea of using single quotes to avoid mass escaping.
I've learned a lot about bash. ))

This is a modified version of choroba's answer.
The same idea, but without "backslashies backslashes tandems", implemented in Lua:

```lua
function run_terminal(text)
   local function q(s) return "'"..s:gsub("'","'\\''").."'" end
   os.execute(
      'gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c "'..q(q("echo "..q(text)..";exec $SHELL"))
   )
end
run_terminal "Some Text"
```

**Edit 3:**
Thanks to Gilles for mentioning "-x COMMAND" option of gnome-terminal.
Quoting is not required with this option, so we can reduce level of quoting inside generated commands:

```lua
function run_terminal(text)
   local function q(s) return "'"..s:gsub("'","'\\''").."'" end
   os.execute("gnome-terminal -x sh -c "..q("echo "..q(text)..";exec $SHELL"))
end
run_terminal "Some Text"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the string, and you'll only have to backslash the quotes. If you quote twice, you need to escape both quote types.

*Update:* Gnome terminal needs triple quoting. Just escape the single quotes twice in the string, and use quoted single quotes around the inserted string. You need to backslash the backslashes in the original string, too.

Proof: I used the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

chomp( my $msg = <> );
$msg =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;           # Quis backslashies backslashes tandem?
$msg =~ s/'/'\\''/g for 1, 2;  # Replace ' by '\'' twice.
$msg =~ s/"/\\"/g;             # Backslash double quotes.
system q(gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo '\\'') . $msg . q('\\''; exec bash"');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: the command `gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c echo\ \"\\(o o)/\";exec\ $SHELL"` fails.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Where are the single quotes?

Comment: It does not work with single quotes too: `gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c echo\ '\\(o o)/';exec\ $SHELL"` fails.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Ah, ok, you want to quote twice. Check the update.

Comment: I need to include text (as immediate string) into the command.  Your example takes the string from environment variable, but where is corresponding bash command to save text into that variable?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: No, $msg is a Perl variable, not an env one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Perl. Please show bash command generated by your program for this input text: `\(o o)/`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: `xterm -e "echo '\(o o)/'; exec bash"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37917/discussion-between-egor-skriptunoff-and-choroba).

Answer (score 2):

Forget quoting and put the text in an environment variable.

Use `-x` to launch a shell.

Don't craft code for `$SHELL`: you don't know what syntax it understands. Run code in `sh`, and call `$SHELL` to invoke an interactive shell.

```
message='HelloWorld' gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'printf %s\\n "$message"; unset message; exec "$SHELL"'
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Don't craft code for $SHELL: you don't know what syntax it understands."?  Does `-c` option not portable?  Or does `echo 'single-quoted text'` behave differently across platforms?  Or does `exec` may not work as expected?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `$SHELL` doesn't have to be a Bourne-like shell. It could be `screen`, `irb`, … anything. It's not a matter of platforms, it's a matter of user choice. Call `sh`, it behaves the same everywhere (for core functionality).

Comment: Do you want to say that $SHELL does not have to implement superset of `sh` features?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, `$SHELL` could be anything, it does not have to be related to `sh` in any way. It's whatever the user wants to use as an *interactive* shell.

Comment: Your solution introduces rather serious problem: you may occasionally erase the content of `$message` env var which may be of importance for other programs invoked by user inside this terminal window.  What would you suggest to solve it?  Should I use GUID as env variable name?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Conventionally, environment variables have uppercase names, and variables used inside scripts have lowercase names. If you're really worried, use a variable name that contains the PID or something.

Comment: Thank you for hints about `-x` and `sh`.  The trade-off you are suggesting (to simplify quoting at the cost of using extra env var) does not seem to be worthwhile for me (in my case commands are generated programmatically).  The usage of env var though is quite reasonable when writing commands manually.  BTW, `exec` is required to be able to close gnome-terminal with just one mouse click.